# Unpack Tuple from C# DLL

Tags: python, c#, dll

I have a C# DLL with method that returns a tuple object.

```csharp
public (int, string) myFunc()
{
  return (0, "hello");
}
```

In my python code I use this DLL and try to unpack the returned tuple.

```python
err, errstring = MyObj.myFunc()
```

However, it doesn't work and gave me this error :

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable ValueTuple[Int32,String] object
```

Can you help me with this error ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Try : results = MyObj.myFunc()

Comment: @jdweng Yes but then I can't unpack results. Thanks to the debugger I can see that I can access the values of this object using results.ItemX (ex: results.Item1) as the manner of how tuples are managed in C#. It's not really elegant ...

Comment: What does `print(type(MyObj.myFunc()))` tell you?.

Comment: @user19077881 <class 'System.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
my_tuple = MyObj.myFunc()

# getting a value from a tuple is similar to a list
err = my_tuple[0]
errString = my_tuple[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work :(